# Not understanding the data flow in UNET-like architetures and having problems with the output of the Conv2DTranspose layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I have a problem or two with the input dimensions of modified U-Net architecture. In order to save your time and better understand/reproduce my results, I'll post the code and the output dimensions. The modified U-Net architecture is the MultiResUNet architecture from https://github.com/nibtehaz/MultiResUNet/blob/master/MultiResUNet.py. and is based on this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04049  Please Don't be turned off by the length of this code. You can simply copy-paste it and it shouldn't take longer than 10 seconds to reproduce my results. Also you don't need a dataset for this. Tested with TF.v1.9 Keras v.2.20.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose, concatenate, BatchNormalization, Activation, add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.activations import relu 

###{ 2D Convolutional layers

   # Arguments: ######################################################################
   #     x {keras layer} -- input layer                                   #
   #     filters {int} -- number of filters                                        #
   #     num_row {int} -- number of rows in filters                               #
   #     num_col {int} -- number of columns in filters                           #

    # Keyword Arguments:
   #     padding {str} -- mode of padding (default: {'same'})
  #      strides {tuple} -- stride of convolution operation (default: {(1, 1)})
 #       activation {str} -- activation function (default: {'relu'})
#        name {str} -- name of the layer (default: {None})

  #  Returns:
  #          [keras layer] -- [output layer]}

      # # ############################################################################


def conv2d_bn(x, filters ,num_row,num_col, padding = "same", strides = (1,1), activation = 'relu', name = None):

    x = Conv2D(filters,(num_row, num_col), strides=strides, padding=padding, use_bias=False)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=3, scale=False)(x)
    if(activation == None):
        return x
    x = Activation(activation, name=name)(x)

    return x

# our 2D transposed Convolution with batch normalization

 # 2D Transposed Convolutional layers

 #   Arguments:      #############################################################
 #       x {keras layer} -- input layer                                         #
 #       filters {int} -- number of filters                                    #
 #       num_row {int} -- number of rows in filters                           #
 #       num_col {int} -- number of columns in filters

 #   Keyword Arguments:
 #       padding {str} -- mode of padding (default: {'same'})
 #       strides {tuple} -- stride of convolution operation (default: {(2, 2)}) 
 #       name {str} -- name of the layer (default: {None})

  #  Returns:
  #      [keras layer] -- [output layer] ###################################

def trans_conv2d_bn(x, filters, num_row, num_col, padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name=None): 

    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters, (num_row, num_col), strides=strides, padding=padding)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=3, scale=False)(x)

    return x

# Our Multi-Res Block 

# Arguments: ############################################################
#        U {int} -- Number of filters in a corrsponding UNet stage     #
#        inp {keras layer} -- input layer                             #

#    Returns:                                                       #
#        [keras layer] -- [output layer]                           #
###################################################################

def MultiResBlock(U, inp, alpha = 1.67):

    W = alpha * U

    shortcut = inp

    shortcut = conv2d_bn(shortcut, int(W*0.167) + int(W*0.333) +
                         int(W*0.5), 1, 1, activation=None, padding='same')

    conv3x3 = conv2d_bn(inp, int(W*0.167), 3, 3,
                        activation='relu', padding='same')

    conv5x5 = conv2d_bn(conv3x3, int(W*0.333), 3, 3,
                        activation='relu', padding='same')

    conv7x7 = conv2d_bn(conv5x5, int(W*0.5), 3, 3,
                        activation='relu', padding='same')

    out = concatenate([conv3x3, conv5x5, conv7x7], axis=3)
    out = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(out)

    out = add([shortcut, out])
    out = Activation('relu')(out)
    out = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(out)

    return out

# Our ResPath:
# ResPath

#    Arguments:#######################################
#        filters {int} -- [description]
#        length {int} -- length of ResPath
#        inp {keras layer} -- input layer 

#    Returns:
#        [keras layer] -- [output layer]#############



def ResPath(filters, length, inp):
    shortcut = inp
    shortcut = conv2d_bn(shortcut, filters, 1, 1,
                         activation=None, padding='same')

    out = conv2d_bn(inp, filters, 3, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')

    out = add([shortcut, out])
    out = Activation('relu')(out)
    out = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(out)

    for i in range(length-1):

        shortcut = out
        shortcut = conv2d_bn(shortcut, filters, 1, 1,
                             activation=None, padding='same')

        out = conv2d_bn(out, filters, 3, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')

        out = add([shortcut, out])
        out = Activation('relu')(out)
        out = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(out)

    return out



#    MultiResUNet

#    Arguments: ############################################
#        height {int} -- height of image 
#        width {int} -- width of image 
#        n_channels {int} -- number of channels in image

#    Returns:
#        [keras model] -- MultiResUNet model###############




def MultiResUnet(height, width, n_channels):



    inputs = Input((height, width, n_channels))

    # downsampling part begins here 

    mresblock1 = MultiResBlock(32, inputs)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(mresblock1)
    mresblock1 = ResPath(32, 4, mresblock1)

    mresblock2 = MultiResBlock(32*2, pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(mresblock2)
    mresblock2 = ResPath(32*2, 3, mresblock2)

    mresblock3 = MultiResBlock(32*4, pool2)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(mresblock3)
    mresblock3 = ResPath(32*4, 2, mresblock3)

    mresblock4 = MultiResBlock(32*8, pool3)


    # Upsampling part 

    up5 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(
        32*4, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(mresblock4), mresblock3], axis=3)
    mresblock5 = MultiResBlock(32*8, up5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(
        32*4, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(mresblock5), mresblock2], axis=3)
    mresblock6 = MultiResBlock(32*4, up6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(
        32*2, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(mresblock6), mresblock1], axis=3)
    mresblock7 = MultiResBlock(32*2, up7)


    conv8 = conv2d_bn(mresblock7, 1, 1, 1, activation='sigmoid')

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv8])

    return model
```

So now back to my problem with mismatched input/output dimensions in the UNet architecture.

If I choose filter height/width (128,128) or (256,256) or (512,512) and do :

```
 model = MultiResUnet(128, 128,3)
 display(model.summary())
```

Tensorflow gives me a perfect result of how the whole architecture looks like. Now if I do this

```
     model = MultiResUnet(36, 36,3)
     display(model.summary())
```

I get this error :

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 model = MultiResUnet(36, 36,3)
>         2 display(model.summary())
>
> in MultiResUnet(height, width,
>   n_channels)
>        25 
>        26        up5 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(
>   ---> 27            32*4, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(mresblock4), mresblock3], axis=3)
>        28        mresblock5 = MultiResBlock(32*8, up5)
>        29
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/MastersThenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py
>   in concatenate(inputs, axis, **kwargs)
>       682       A tensor, the concatenation of the inputs alongside axis `axis`.
>       683   """
>   --> 684   return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
>       685 
>       686
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/MastersThenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       694         if all(hasattr(x, 'get_shape') for x in input_list):
>       695           input_shapes = nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.get_shape(), inputs)
>   --> 696         self.build(input_shapes)
>       697 
>       698       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/MastersThenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py
>   in wrapper(instance, input_shape)
>       146       else:
>       147         input_shape = tuple(tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list())
>   --> 148     output_shape = fn(instance, input_shape)
>       149     if output_shape is not None:
>       150       if isinstance(output_shape, list):
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/MastersThenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py
>   in build(self, input_shape)
>       388                        'inputs with matching shapes '
>       389                        'except for the concat axis. '
>   --> 390                        'Got inputs shapes: %s' % (input_shape))
>       391 
>       392   def _merge_function(self, inputs):
>
> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
>   except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 8, 8, 128),
>   (None, 9, 9, 128)]

Why does the Conv2DTranspose give me the wrong dimension

> (None, 8, 8, 128)

instead of

> (None, 9, 9, 128)

and why doesn't the Concat function complain when I choose filter sizes like (128,128),(256,256) and etc. (multiples of 32)
**So to generalize this question how can I make this UNet architecture work with any filter size** and how can I deal with the Conv2DTranspose layer producing an output that has one dimension less(width/height) than the actually needed dimension(when the filter size isn't a multiple of 32 or is not symmetric) and why doesn't this happen with other filter sizes that are a multiple of the 32. And what If I had **variable Input sizes** ??

Any help would be highly appreciated.

cheers, 
H

Answer (score 6, accepted):

U-Net family of models (such as the MultiResUNet model above) follow an encoder-decoder architecture. **Encoder** is a down-sampling path with feature extraction whereas the **decoder** an upsampling one. Feature maps from encoder are **concatenated** at the decoder through *skip-connections*. These feature maps are concatenated at the last axis, the **'channel'** axis (considering the features to be having dimensions [batch_size, height, width, channels]). Now, for the features to be concatenated at any axis ('channel' axis, in our case), the dimensions at all the other axes **must** match.

In the above model architecture, there are **3 downsampling/max-pooling** operations being performed (through `MaxPooling2D`)in the encoder path. At the decoder path **3 upsampling/transpose-conv** operations are performed, aiming to restore the image back to the full dimension. However, for the concatenations (through skip-connections) to happen, the downsampled and upsampled feature dimensions of *height, width & batch_size* should remain identical at every "level" of the model. I'll illustrate this with the examples you mentioned in the question:

**1st case** : Input dimensions **(128,128,3)** :   128 -> 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 32 -> 64 -> 128

**2nd case**: Input dimensions **(36,36,3)** :   36 -> 18 -> **9 -> 4 -> 8** -> 16 -> 32

In the 2nd case, when the *height* and *width* of feature map reaches *9* in the encoder path, further downsampling leads to a dimension change (loss) that *cannot be regained in the decoder* while upsampling. Hence, it throws an error due to inability to concatenate feature maps of dimensions **[(None, 8, 8, 128)]** & **[(None, 9, 9, 128)]**.

In general, for a simple encoder-decoder model (with skip-connections) having '**n**' downsampling (`MaxPooling2D`) layers, the input dimension must be a **multiple of 2^n** to be able to concatenate the model's encoder features at the decoder. In this case **n=3**, hence the input must be a multiple of **8** to not run into these dimension mismatch errors.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Balraj Ashwath for the great answer! Then, if your input has shape **h** and you want to use this architecture with depth **d** (**h** >= 2^**d**), one possibility is to pad the dimension of **h** with **delta_h** zeros, given by the following expression:

```
import numpy as np

h, d = 36, 3
delta_h = np.ceil(h/(2**d)) * (2**d) - h
print(delta_h)
> 4.0
```

Then, following the example of @Balraj Ashwath:

```
40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 10 -> 20 -> 40
```