# Tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: All dimensions except 3 must match

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to train a U-net model to use, when I ready to train

it show the error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  All dimensions except 3 must match. Input 1 has shape [2 60 44 256] and doesn't match input 0 with shape [2 60 45 
256].
```

but I check my layer by layer and check my data (180*240)
and can't find where is wrong.
Please help me if my structure has error or somewhat. thanks!!

my model sturcture:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model
```

and I call it from

```
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0.2,
                    width_shift_range=0.05,
                    height_shift_range=0.05,
                    shear_range=0.05,
                    zoom_range=0.05,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    fill_mode='nearest')

myGene = trainGenerator(2,'data/diploma/train','image','label',data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None
                        , target_size=(240, 180))

model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_membrane.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=1,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

and error occurs in `fit.`

Comment: It is likely originates from your concatenation layers where it expects to all dimensions be equal, except the axis you want to concat which is axis=3. Check the dimensions when it reaches to concatenation layers. Check with `model.summary()`.

Comment: And this is because your input shape which is `240,180` is not compatible with the model architecture. When it reaches to concatenate layers, the dimensions are not equal, and it con not concatenate them. You may try `target_size=(240, 240)`.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing what Kaveh said, the problem is with the combination of the model architecture and the input image size (180x240). In your model there are four pooling layers that reduce the image size by 2 each time. Thus the first image dimension goes 180 -> 90 -> 45 - > 22 ("floor of 22.5") ...
Then in the upsampling path 22 -> 44 -> ... . This is why if you look at the error it says it expects 45 but it is getting 44.
The solution is either changing the model architecture (reducing the number of pooling layers) or make the image dimensions multiple of 16 (for example 192x240).

This post has a good explanation of the problem:

[Not understanding the data flow in UNET-like architetures and having problems with the output of the Conv2DTranspose layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063797/not-understanding-the-data-flow-in-unet-like-architetures-and-having-problems-wi)